# keep-with-next strange behaviour

Tags: xsl-fo

I have 2 tables defined in my document. Inside the first one I use attribute `keep-with-next="1"` on every row to keep the rows together.

But this attribute also affects the next table, so the first table is trying to stay with the next table.

As a result I get both tables the second page and the first page is blank.

Is it possible to stop this or to set the context of 'keep-with-next' to be only within a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keep-together.within-page="always" on the fo:table element to keep that whole table together on a page.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I used `keep-together` and it helped. Is it correct that `keep-with-next` on one table affect the next one?

Comment: Well, I would not use your method and you posted no example, however if you marked the last row to keep with next and the next thing is a table ... then ?

Comment: Ok, I just thought that it's limited to the table I declared it in.